# Не могу заменить данные на хостинге, nginx + uwsgi

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

Сайт бы разработан до меня.

ip сайта, совпадает с ip хостинга.

Нужно поменять файлы находящиеся по пути `alias`.

Файлы при замене или изменению не меняются.

Также если остановить работу `nginx` (`service nginx stop`).

Сайт продолжает работу.

Мне подсказали, что возможно стоит балансировщик.

В конфигах `nginx` его не видел.

Вопрос что нужно искать?

Связаться с прошлыми разработчиками - невозможно, уехали за границу.

Данные, которые имею, от одного хостинга.

Comment: Такими темпами, видимо, будет проще и быстрее заказать работу профессиональному системному администратору

Comment: Так и сделал. Пытаюсь ускорить процесс.

Answer (score 0):

И не увидите, если это вышестоящий реверс прокси. Остановите nginx и посмотрите не висят-ли ещё какие nginx-ы. (`ps -ax|grep nginx`) Чудес-то не бывает.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали. Остановил `nginx`. Прописал. И вот ответ.  `59709 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep nginx `

Comment: Хмм... Чудеса. Ну погрепайте httpd (`ps -ax|grep httpd`) может там и не нжинкс вовсе, а индеец. А вообще  тогда уж искать лучше так:
`sudo lsof -i4@0:80|grep -i listen`
Покажет кто висит на 80-м порту.

Comment: Разобрался) Там стоят разные виртуалки. При подключение по Ip я получаю одну и могу ходить по разным. Ту что дали, бесполезна со стороны сервера. Перейдя на нужную все работает. Путаница была из-за того, что настройки прописаны на двух виртуалках.

Comment: Просто я  не думал, что так будут делать. Сайт - многостраничник, простейший.  Python Django + angular + celery. Нагрузка на сайт минимальная.